# WPF XAML display content in a ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I need to display a number in a square, centered horizontally and vertically.

When I tried to use a label for that purpose, it seemed like it ignored the centering completely. So I decided to use a grid and display a label on the grid as that centers perfectly.

I need to use a template as there's several themes available. From what I've found on the internet, I thought this ( ignoring the centering for now )

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ClockTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <Label>
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#376092"/>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

would be correct. Using it as follows:

```
<ContentControl  Content="20" Height="64" Width="64" Template="{DynamicResource ClockTemplate}"/>
```

the content is not displayed tho, what am I doing wrong? Also, is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't work, but if you bind the `Content` property of the label to the `Content` property of the templated control rather than using an additional `ContentPresenter`, the number is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding this is not the correct approach. Instead of creating `ControlTemplate` you have to write a `Style` for your control like below, also use `StaticResource` binding if possible. It is faster than `Dynamic` binding. Please not that, I have not mentioned the `Label` size inside the `ControlTemplate`. Please do it based on your needs

```
<Style x:Key="ContentControlStyle"
           TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Grid Background="White">
                        <Label Foreground="#376092"
                               Width="200"
                               Height="100" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

bind your `ContentControl` with the newly created `Style` like below

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ContentControlStyle} ">
```

If your requirement is only to set some value in `ContentControl`, use `Label` instead and change the `Style` of the `Label`. Because `ContentControl` is heavy

Comment: 1) I need to use dynamic resource for the runtime style changes 2) It still doesn't display the content.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now the label will show the value which you set as content for content control

Comment: Okey, it works. Whats the difference between this and my approach? ( I made my code snippet work thanks to Mapper's tip )

Comment: this link will give you some idea http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295273.aspx